# what is the meaning of LocalGC/GlobalGC/SystemGC in IBM J9 JavaCore

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I got a javacore when jvm crash, but i can't understand the GC history segment. What the LocalGC/GlobalGC/SystemGC stands for?
Many thanks!

```
1STGCHTYPE     GC History  
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:918796000 GMT j9mm.60 -   Class unloading start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:918781000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:912430000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:912413000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:872687000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:872660000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2853 soft=1164 phantom=20 finalizers=384 globalcount=231 scavengecount=397 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:48:872300000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.073 newspace=4022424/60397568 oldspace=981846840/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:22:649438000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90138 flipbytes=5837752 newspace=54236992/60397568 oldspace=981848832/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:22:637242000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=397 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:22:637218000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:21:424334000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=88056 flipbytes=5740288 newspace=54540368/60397568 oldspace=981935408/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:21:395216000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=396 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:21:395186000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:20:118355000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=89809 flipbytes=5913320 newspace=54403616/60397568 oldspace=982408904/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:20:89486000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=395 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:20:89455000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:18:876887000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90096 flipbytes=5943112 newspace=54281264/60397568 oldspace=982614504/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:18:862146000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=394 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:18:862121000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:17:692277000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90207 flipbytes=5949208 newspace=54112984/60397568 oldspace=982793112/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:17:670489000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=393 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:17:670464000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:16:455289000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90332 flipbytes=5952640 newspace=54113200/60397568 oldspace=982975872/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:16:433555000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=392 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:16:433529000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:15:304510000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90287 flipbytes=5947072 newspace=54283360/60397568 oldspace=983168536/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:15:283058000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=391 weakrefs=2840 soft=1158 phantom=20 finalizers=376 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:15:283032000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:13:959191000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90616 flipbytes=5964184 newspace=54011616/60269568 oldspace=983360752/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:13:945970000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=390 weakrefs=2840 soft=1162 phantom=20 finalizers=378 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:13:945946000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:12:907889000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=90406 flipbytes=5767016 newspace=53103184/59038720 oldspace=983591256/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:12:893607000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=230 scavengecount=389 weakrefs=2846 soft=1165 phantom=20 finalizers=403 
3STHSTTYPE     06:49:12:893581000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:870649000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57301424/60397568 oldspace=983842608/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:870622000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2846 soft=1148 phantom=20 finalizers=376 newspace=57301424/60397568 oldspace=983842608/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:870543000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:864220000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:864208000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:809822000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:809795000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2850 soft=1264 phantom=20 finalizers=384 globalcount=230 scavengecount=388 
3STHSTTYPE     06:48:48:809430000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.077 newspace=9527800/60397568 oldspace=983755144/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:808722000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57401760/60397568 oldspace=983759440/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:808694000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2846 soft=1162 phantom=20 finalizers=376 newspace=57401760/60397568 oldspace=983759440/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:808616000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:802436000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:802423000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:746999000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:746972000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2850 soft=1220 phantom=20 finalizers=380 globalcount=229 scavengecount=388 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:48:746605000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.074 newspace=33698008/60397568 oldspace=983693288/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:06:502600000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=40139 flipbytes=3022592 newspace=57224568/60397568 oldspace=983693336/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:06:491846000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=228 scavengecount=388 weakrefs=2845 soft=1240 phantom=20 finalizers=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:47:06:491822000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:746220000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57167480/60397568 oldspace=983884056/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:746192000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2838 soft=1168 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=57167480/60397568 oldspace=983884056/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:746104000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:741406000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:741392000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:697422000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:697395000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2838 soft=1176 phantom=20 finalizers=377 globalcount=228 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:46:48:697043000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.067 newspace=47752152/60397568 oldspace=983878128/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:694718000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57327272/60397568 oldspace=983878176/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:694692000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2838 soft=1173 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=57327272/60397568 oldspace=983878176/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:694601000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:688358000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:688344000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:633645000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:633618000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2878 soft=1268 phantom=20 finalizers=386 globalcount=227 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:45:48:633260000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.075 newspace=30163040/60397568 oldspace=983836992/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:632920000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57252560/60397568 oldspace=983839584/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:632891000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2848 soft=1171 phantom=20 finalizers=376 newspace=57252560/60397568 oldspace=983839584/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:632802000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:628101000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:628087000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:575421000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:575393000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2852 soft=1227 phantom=20 finalizers=380 globalcount=226 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:44:48:575028000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.076 newspace=34103512/60397568 oldspace=983829536/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:565148000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57376224/60397568 oldspace=983829584/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:565121000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2834 soft=1173 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=57376224/60397568 oldspace=983829584/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:565031000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:558842000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:558829000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:525392000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:525364000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2834 soft=1199 phantom=20 finalizers=381 globalcount=225 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:43:48:524995000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.083 newspace=36182232/60397568 oldspace=983808712/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:524638000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57386424/60397568 oldspace=983810240/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:524610000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2834 soft=1176 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=57386424/60397568 oldspace=983810240/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:524523000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:518725000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:518712000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:464206000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:464178000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2834 soft=1216 phantom=20 finalizers=381 globalcount=224 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:42:48:463815000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.080 newspace=39931504/60397568 oldspace=983810192/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:454217000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=57537296/60397568 oldspace=983810240/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:454190000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2834 soft=1176 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=57537296/60397568 oldspace=983810240/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:454111000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:447998000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:447985000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:393305000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:393277000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2840 soft=1180 phantom=20 finalizers=375 globalcount=223 scavengecount=387 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:48:392909000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.081 newspace=52249608/60397568 oldspace=983787400/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:21:359379000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=41832 flipbytes=2898488 newspace=57385008/60397568 oldspace=983787448/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:21:345579000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=222 scavengecount=387 weakrefs=2842 soft=1229 phantom=20 finalizers=384 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:21:345556000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:04:671043000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=68569 flipbytes=4083904 newspace=56170240/60397568 oldspace=984957880/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:04:661273000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=222 scavengecount=386 weakrefs=2840 soft=1179 phantom=20 finalizers=374 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:04:661250000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:03:789521000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=65831 flipbytes=3909376 newspace=56302368/60397568 oldspace=984957880/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:03:779410000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=222 scavengecount=385 weakrefs=2840 soft=1259 phantom=20 finalizers=381 
3STHSTTYPE     06:41:03:779386000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:388752000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56524640/60397568 oldspace=984965784/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:388725000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2834 soft=1174 phantom=20 finalizers=374 newspace=56524640/60397568 oldspace=984965784/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:388635000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:382147000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:382133000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:327465000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:327437000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2848 soft=1380 phantom=20 finalizers=392 globalcount=222 scavengecount=384 
3STHSTTYPE     06:40:48:327100000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.087 newspace=9458328/60397568 oldspace=984746256/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:326740000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56644528/60397568 oldspace=984750984/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:326711000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2844 soft=1176 phantom=20 finalizers=375 newspace=56644528/60397568 oldspace=984750984/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:326623000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:321384000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:321372000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:267053000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:267026000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2844 soft=1194 phantom=20 finalizers=377 globalcount=221 scavengecount=384 
3STHSTTYPE     06:39:48:266665000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.087 newspace=50544576/60397568 oldspace=984643408/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:266051000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56680224/60397568 oldspace=984643456/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:266020000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2838 soft=1182 phantom=20 finalizers=373 newspace=56680224/60397568 oldspace=984643456/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:265943000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:259764000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:259754000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:225660000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:225633000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2852 soft=1251 phantom=20 finalizers=378 globalcount=220 scavengecount=384 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:48:225289000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.087 newspace=29104864/60397568 oldspace=984623848/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:21:598485000 GMT j9mm.65 -   LocalGC end: rememberedsetoverflow=0 causedrememberedsetoverflow=0 scancacheoverflow=0 failedflipcount=0 failedflipbytes=0 failedtenurecount=0 failedtenurebytes=0 flipcount=61526 flipbytes=3939664 newspace=56256360/60397568 oldspace=984627960/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 tenureage=14 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:21:584740000 GMT j9mm.64 -   LocalGC start: globalcount=219 scavengecount=384 weakrefs=2861 soft=1329 phantom=20 finalizers=386 
3STHSTTYPE     06:38:21:584717000 GMT j9mm.63 -   Set scavenger backout flag=false 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:224903000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56398880/60397568 oldspace=984627960/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:224875000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2849 soft=1185 phantom=20 finalizers=373 newspace=56398880/60397568 oldspace=984627960/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:224786000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:218806000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:218793000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:163746000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:163718000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2856 soft=1267 phantom=20 finalizers=382 globalcount=219 scavengecount=383 
3STHSTTYPE     06:37:48:163343000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.085 newspace=12010848/60397568 oldspace=984587896/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:156116000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56649080/60397568 oldspace=984594952/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:156084000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2839 soft=1186 phantom=19 finalizers=373 newspace=56649080/60397568 oldspace=984594952/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:156000000 GMT j9mm.57 -   Sweep end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:148638000 GMT j9mm.56 -   Sweep start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:148620000 GMT j9mm.55 -   Mark end 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:83794000 GMT j9mm.54 -   Mark start 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:83761000 GMT j9mm.52 -   GlobalGC start: weakrefs=2862 soft=1387 phantom=19 finalizers=385 globalcount=218 scavengecount=383 
3STHSTTYPE     06:36:48:83361000 GMT j9mm.50 -   SystemGC start: exclusiveaccessms=0.108 newspace=2142152/60397568 oldspace=984581856/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:35:48:76369000 GMT j9mm.51 -   SystemGC end: newspace=56774872/60397568 oldspace=984586272/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648 
3STHSTTYPE     06:35:48:76342000 GMT j9mm.53 -   GlobalGC end: workstackoverflow=0 overflowcount=0 weakrefs=2848 soft=1184 phantom=19 finalizers=373 newspace=56774872/60397568 oldspace=984586272/1006632960 loa=50331648/50331648
```

Answer (score 1):

You see this entries if you use a gencon generational garbage collector on an IBM Java VM.

A LocalGC only collects the Nursery space, which is the space where all small objects get created. This is also called scavenging and the scavengecount value tells you how many of those ran since the JVM was started.

The GlobalGC collects the tenured space.

A SystemGC is a global GC that was invoked through a java.lang.System.gc() method call. Note that when creating a heap dump through SIGQUIT, System.gc() is called before dumping to ensure a smaller dump size.

See the Java Diagnostics Guide for more information on Nursery and Tenured Spaces.